# Qt Data Visualization: How to integrate a Q3DScatter graph into a Widget in a Main Window?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to display a Q3DScatter graph in a Main Window designed with Qt Designer so I've added a widget to the main window but I don't know how to embed the graph object in this widget. I tried to create a widget "container" programmatically and embed the graph in it and then putting the widget in a QHBoxLayout (which has been added to the main window using Qt Designer) using the following code in my main window's constructor:

```
...
Q3DScatter *graph = new Q3DScatter();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
ui->horizontal_layout->addWidget(container, 1);
```

But the window appears to be empty when executing. I'd really appreciate some help.

EDIT: Here's the full code of my main window constructor:

```
ResultsWindow::ResultsWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ResultsWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Q3DScatter *graph = new Q3DScatter();

    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);

    ui->horizontal_layout->addWidget(container, 1);
}
```

And here's the main code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ResultsWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

EDIT 2: I forgot to specify that the horizontal layout is embedded in a GridLayout. I tried to create a new project and my code actually works perfectly when I add a horizontal layout directly to the main window. So could the problem be due to the GridLayout?

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not had problems, you could give us more information.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the full code of my Main window constructor, I execute it from main like this: 
QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ResultsWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();

Comment: It is the same code that I tried, you could show a screenshot or share your code using github, drive, dropbox, ect

Comment: I created a new project and indeed the code I've posted works perfectly! I forgot to say that I am using a GridLayout in my main window, in which I've added my horizontal layout into, could it be because of this ?